# Is there a function such that the integral of the function converges, yet the absolute value of the function diverges.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

It's easy to show that there's a function such that $\int_1^\infty f $ diverges, but $\int_1^\infty |f|$ converges, such as $f = 1/(-1+x)$.

But is there a function such that $\int_1^\infty f $ converges, but $\int_1^\infty |f| $ diverges?

Comment: Your example function diverges both with and without absolute value.

Answer (score 5):

First I recall that
$$\text {if}\quad \int_1^\infty |f|\quad\text{ converges then so does }\quad  \int_1^\infty f$$

The integral
$$\int_1^\infty\frac{ \sin x}{x}dx$$
is convergent but 
$$\int_1^\infty\frac{ |\sin x|}{x}dx$$
is divergent.

Comment: Nice!!${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1):

Sami is correct.  Here are some more details.

$$\left|\int_a^{\infty} f(x) \, dx\right| \leq \int_a^{\infty} \left|f(x)\right| \, dx.$$

Thus, if the second integral converges then certainly the first does as well.

Next, it's not too hard to show that

$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} \, dx = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} \, dx$$

and that this last series converges by the alternating series test.

Finally, note that

$$\int_{\frac{2n+1}{2}\pi-\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{2n+1}{2}\pi+\frac{\pi}{4}} 
\left|\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\right|\,dx > \frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\frac{1}{\frac{2n+1}{2}\pi-\frac{\pi}{4}} > \frac{1}{4n}.$$

This is simply a lower bound for the function on the interval times the length of the interval.  It follows that

$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} \, dx$$

is comparable to

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{4n}$$

which is a divergent series.

Answer (score 0):

What about $x\mapsto\frac{\sin(x-1)}{x-1}$? (by definition of what you ask, it cannot Lebesgue integrable, but $\int_{0}^{\uparrow\infty} \frac{\sin x}{x} dx$ does converge to $\frac{\pi}{2}$; and I 'm almost sure to recall that the integral of its absolute value diverges).