# An improper integral that diverges

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

I want to show that the integral
\begin{align*}
\int_1^{\infty} \frac{|\sin x|}{x} \text{ d}x  
\end{align*}
diverges without sketching the function and obtain the divergence of the integral geometrically. I wonder if the comparison test works here.

I appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: $\left|\sin(x)\right|$ has a positive mean value, hence the integral is divergent by Kronecker's Lemma.

Comment: Clarify please. I don’t know what is meant by Kronecker’s Lemma.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker%27s_lemma

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/380590/587007

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Also used in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/104678):
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi}\frac{|\sin(x)\,|}x\,\mathrm{d}x
&\ge\frac1{(k+1)\pi}\int_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi}|\sin(x)\,|\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac2{(k+1)\pi}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: This is so good. Thanks.